# Make Javascript event happen only when scrolled to

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I currently have a JavaScript creating small pop ups when the page loads. I would like to make them appear only when the user scrolls down to where they appear (over a photo).

Is this possible?

Here is the code:

```
jQuery(function(){
// initialize of labels
$('.labels a#label1').fadeIn(100).effect('bounce', { times:3 }, 300, function() {
    $('.labels a#label2').fadeIn(100).effect('bounce', { times:3 }, 300, function() {
        $('.labels a#label3').fadeIn(100).effect('bounce', { times:3 }, 300, function() {
            $('.labels a#label4').fadeIn(100).effect('bounce', { times:3 }, 300, function() {
                $('.labels a#label6').fadeIn(100).effect('bounce', { times:3 }, 300, function() {
                    $('.labels a#label5').fadeIn(100).effect('bounce', { times:3 }, 300);
                });
            });
        });
    });
});

// dialog close
$('.dialog .close').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(500);
    return false;
});

// display dialog on click by labels
$('.labels a').click(function() {
    $('.dialog p').html( $(this).find('p').html() ).parent().fadeIn(500);
    return false;
});

// close dialog on click outside
$('.container').click(function() {
    $('.dialog').fadeOut(500);
});
});
```

Comment: I would suggest looking into something like scrollspy (comes with bootstrap) to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this question: [How to animate this when scrolled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27747983/how-to-animate-this-when-scrolled/27748980#27748980)

Here is the basic code you want to use:

```
<script>
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $('.labels').each(function(){
        var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;

        var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (imagePos < topOfWindow + 400) {
            $(this).fadeIn(100).effect('bounce', { times:3 }, 300);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

You will also want to call the function on page load to initialize any elements that are visible without having to scroll

The OP in the question above links to a page with lots of cool animations you can use as well